# Passing Viewbag Data from View to Controller in ASP.Net MVC3 Razor

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

In my ASP.Net MVC3 Razor project i  have to pass value from view to controller.The view contains one submit button  that is used to pass selected image file and two other input data.This two input data is from a controller named "FileUpload"(ViewBag.Data1 = CusId;ViewBag.Data2 = Name;).When submitting the button i have to pass these three (Image,CusId,Name) to another controller to upload the image file.

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(int CusId, string Name)
        {
            ViewBag.Data1 = CusId;
            ViewBag.Data2 = Name;

            return View();



        }

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadPhoto(ElixiCustPro elixi, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            //return null;
            try
            {
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    if ((file.ContentType == "image/jpeg") || (file.ContentType == "image/gif") || (file.ContentType == "image/png"))//check allow jpg, gif, png
                    {
                        elixi.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                        file.InputStream.Read(elixi.Image, 0, file.ContentLength);
                        var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ElixirFiles/UploadImagesElixir/"), filename);
                        file.SaveAs(path);

                        ecp.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                        ecp.ImageUrl = path;


                        ment.ElixiProData.Add(ecp);
                        ment.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("ImageResult");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View(ex.Message.ToString());
            }


            return View();
        }
```

View Code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPhoto", "Home", FormMethod.Post,  new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                    {
          @*              <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                            Customer ID</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CusId, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>

                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                            Customer Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
                        </div>*@
                        <input type="hidden" id="id" />
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                                    DMIT Image</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                     @ViewBag.Data1
                                     @ViewBag.Data2
                                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ViewBag can't pass data back to controller. You should post those values back inside the form. Easiest thing would be to not to use ViewBag and add the data to model type.

Then you can pass them with hidden inputs using HTML helpers like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(item => item.CustomerId)
@Html.HiddenFor(item => item.ImageId)
```

If that's not possible, you can add the hidden inputs manually. Just keep in mind that the name attributes are important for model binding.

```
<input type="hidden" name="CustomerId" value="@ViewBag.Data1" />
```

Comment: Hello here am not using any model in this view page

Comment: Question: Wouldn't this be insecure? Since it is a hidden input somebody may inspect the code and see the value?

Comment: @Nick Hidden input is just a convenient way to post form data, it's not a security feature. You should validate every input on the server side.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Duly noted. Thank you!

Comment: @Nick You mentioned somebody may inspect the code..will they be able to change the value as well?

Comment: Can you pass a list like this? Doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 13):

Yes you cannot pass a Viewbag from view to controller.
But you can pass them using TempData.

Add this to your View.

```
@{TempData["Data1"]=ViewBag.Data1}
@{TempData["Data2"]=ViewBag.Data2}
```

But this TempData passes the information as an object.
So typecasting is necessary in your Controller.

```
int x=Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Data1"]);
string y=(TempData["Data2"]).ToString();
```

I tried,it is working.

or you can send TempData from Controller in get method,and use the same to pass from view to post method instead of Viewbag.

Comment: you need a `;` before the curly brackets in the tempdata assignment